# git lfs ls-files of a specific commit

Tags: git, git-lfs

I wanted to see how the lfs track list was at a specific commit.

Tried:

`git lfs ls-files <commit sha>`

But it listed me files that could not be there at that commit, most probably this is printing me files being tracked right now, ignoring the ref commit I passed.

The help of the commad says:

```
$ git lfs ls-files --help
git lfs ls-files [<ref>]

Display paths of Git LFS files that are found in the tree at the given
reference.  If no reference is given, scan the currently checked-out branch.
An asterisk (*) after the OID indicates a LFS pointer, a minus (-) a full object.
```

Is there any way of doing this? Am I missing something?

EDIT because of the questions:
Lets say in my initial commmit (51915d5) I've only commited a .gitattributes and a .gitignore file.

If I try:

```
git lfs ls-files 51915d5
```

It prints me **ALL** the files tracked by LFS **in my last commit.**

Comment: `git lfs ls-files <commit sha>` works as expected for me.  Can you show a specific command that isn't doing what you'd expect?